Не работает Shift при сглаживании полигонов в Blender
В режиме скульптинга при использовании сочетания клавиш Shift + ЛКМ объект должен сглаживаться, но вместо этого его полигоны вылазят наружу. Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего такой эффект, как это исправить?
Вот что у меня получается:



А должно быть вот так:

